# Stepper Motor button control with A4988 Driver

Tags: pins, button, stepper-motor

So I'm quite new to programming and have inevitably worked myself into a corner. What I am trying to accomplish is to allow for a stepper motor, (powered by an A4988 driver) to move with the push of a button. The schematic is as follows:
 [image: Motor Circuit]

And the code to try and make the motor move with a button is:

```cpp
const int = buttonPin = 2; 
const int = stepPin = 3;
const int = dirPin = 4;

int buttonState = 0;

void setup(){
    pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPin,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (buttonState = HIGH){
       digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);{
           digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
           delayMicroseconds(500); 
           digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
           delayMicroseconds(500);
           }
    }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seperate each code part and test each part. First check if you can detect a push on the button by turning on a led or sending a message to the serial monitor. Then create for example 100 steps for the stepper mode in code. Then you can put the two things together. Please add extra information to your question: which stepper motor is is?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a description of the problem. I can see one definite problem with your code and one thing which probably isn't what you want, but it would be useful to know how it doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes microstepping doesn't work with particular motors. I suggest configuring the driver board for full step operation until you get your code working properly.